# Looking for good program for cataloging DVD, Video files, ebook

Tags: windows, ebook, cataloging

I'm looking for a windows program for cataloging my DVD, video files, ebook, etc...

The program must have some retrieval of information from the internet and from the files themselves.

Also, one MUST HAVE requirement is that if a file/ebook changes location, I need to be able to change it in the software. Even better if the program allows bulk updating...

---

### Update

Order of preference is: open-source, freeware, shareware, commercial.

Comment: Too bad a lot of program's only support Movies or Music and not eBooks... Plus a lot of freeware looks like it was made for Win98...

Comment: All I could find so far was crapware...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found something great: [Data Crow](http://datacrow.net/)

Programmed in Java so it runs everywhere. Great application, supported and source code is available.

Also found: [eLibrary](http://www.openelibrary.org/) although it only covers Ebooks...

Answer (score 2):

WhereIsIt - http://www.whereisit-soft.com/

Comment: Well, this is a nice program but it would seem to be pretty thin on supporting ebooks...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all-in-one solution for organizing everything, but I know a good programs for organizing video and books. It is **All My Movies** and **All My Books**, they both are available on [Bolide Software](http://www.bolidesoft.com) website. They are shareware. And yes, it is possible to change the path to the linked video/book files with these programs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest libra, but their site seems to be down at the moment its free, and supports scanning in ISBN numbers from a webcam. Windows only though

Comment: Site is totally gone and so is the program. Not actively developed anymore unfortunately... :(

Answer (score 0):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) for eBooks. It's been in active development for years and has VERY regular updates (Sometimes too often for my liking) and bug fixes.
I currently have a single Calibre (SQLite3 backed) database with 16,718 eBooks and Calibre doesn't even break a sweat.

Calibre is written in Python and is offered for any operating system that can run a Python interpreter & QT extensions or use the bundled interpreter distributed with the main builds.

Installers are available for the following platforms as of this writing:

- Windows (Separate installers for 32 & 64 bit architectures)
- Windows Portable for flash drives, etc.
- Mac OSX
- Linux