# CD/DVD cataloging software?

Tags: software-rec, dvd, database, compact-disc, cataloging

I'm looking for freeware, or preferably open source CD/DVD cataloging applications.

Right now I'm testing http://www.gentibus.com/us/Download.htm, anyone got any other suggestions?

I'd like the software to be actively maintained and not released and left behind.

I'm looking for software which allows me to catalog, sort, search my DVDs/CDs into databases.

Like I've 1 group of 10 dvds only with Fonts etc. I want to read the content into a Database called "Fonts'".

Another group of 5 DVD's with Stockimages, and I want to read all 5 DVDs into the Database "Stock Images".

Then I want this software to be able to open Database "Stock Images", I want to be able to browse DVD 1 - 5 and to see DVD 1 - 5's contents without having the DVD's in the optical drive.

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/11409/looking-for-good-program-for-cataloging-dvd-video-files-ebook)

Comment: Related yes, but nothing there what I seek. WhereIsIt is...meh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azzul](http://sourceforge.net/projects/azzul/) was what I was looking for!

Comment: Wise for small databases. Azzul uses a lot of memory, because it loads all data into memory, optmized for peformance, so a small databse (100k files) uses about 25MB. Can't imagine 1 milion files or more. Azzul also doesn't free or even reuse memory consumed for search (~50MB on 2 search querries on 100k file database).

Comment: Possible alternative (slower, memory saver, can search inside archives): [Disk Explorer Proffestional](http://www.tjelinek.com/main.php?section=d) (freeware).